# ¿Por qué cuando una carpeta es comprimida en Linux, el sistema operativo trunca el nombre de la carpeta comprimida?

Tags: linux, tar

Cuando comprimo una carpeta del sistema, a través de una interfaz gráfica con el botón derecho del mouse, por ejemplo:  */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d*

El sistema operativo crea una carpeta comprimida con el nombre  *xorg.conf.tar.gz*  en lugar de  *xorg.conf.d.tar.gz*

Al escribir el comando  '*tar -xzcf foldername.tar.gz*'   a través del terminal, muestra un error.
¿Alguien sabe por qué ocurre el truncamiento del nombre de la carpeta?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes especificar el nombre del fichero de salida

Comment: Sí, naturalmente. El fichero de salida me gustaría que fuese el mismo nombre de la carpeta, es decir, si la carpeta se llama  xorg.conf.d  , me gustaría que el nombre fuese xorg.conf.d.tar.gz

Comment: Quiero decir que en el comando puedes especificar el nombre que quieras de salida, de sea forma no tendras problema, y tambien para descompriomir estas usando la opcion -c que significa comprimir....

Comment: Para comprimir :  tar czvf (carpeta a comprimir) (nombre del fichero comprimido)     Para descomprimir : tar zxvf (fichero comprimido) -C (ruta donde descomprimir)

Comment: No. No me estás entendiendo lo que he planteado.
Cuando escribo en consola:
tar -xzcf  xorg.conf.d.tar.gz  xorg.conf.d
No lo hace. Y cuando lo hago por interfaz gráfica, sobre la carpeta que quiero comprimir, le quita la d, y me la deja en un estado como corrupta.

Comment: Entiendo tu problema, pero no me has leido muy bien. Para comprimir un archivo , no puedes especificar la opción -x (significa descomprimir) asi que no me extraña que por consola no te funcione. El comportamiento por interfaz gráfica lo desconozco. Pero si escribes bien el comando , te funcionará sin problemas. Prueba a hacer lo que te digo y escribir bien el comando.

Answer (score 0):

Para comprimir un fichero con el comando tar :

tar (opciones) (nombre de fichero comprimido) (directorio/fichero a comprimir)

opciones compresion:

```
    -c create
    -f file
    -v verbose
    -t list
    -z formato gzip
...
```

opciones descompresion :

```
    -x extract
    -f file
...
```

Por lo tanto para comprimir necesitarass usar la opcion -c 
y para descomprimir usar la opción -x

Tus comandos deberían quedar :

comprimir:

```
tar zcvf xorg.conf.d.tar.gz /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

descomprimir:

```
tar zxvf xorg.conf.d.tar.gz -C (ruta destino)
```